# how to set custom input format in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing MapReduce program and using classes in org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*. Can anybody tell me cause of this error? My CustomInputFormat class extends InputFormat and I have overridden createRecordReader method.

Signature of my CustomInputFormat is:

```
class ParagraphInputFormat extends InputFormat {

    @Override
    public RecordReader createRecordReader(InputSplit arg0,
        TaskAttemptContext arg1) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new CustomRecordReader();
    }

    @Override
    public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext arg0) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

And Signature of CustomRecordReader is  `class CustomRecordReader extends RecordReader`

While declaring this class I used org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*. I am confused between org.apache.hadoop.mapred.* and org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*. Eclipse keeps on showing deprecated messages sometimes. I heard that apache has added some classes then removed those and then again added previous classes. Is is due to that? Is it affecting my code?

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(new Configuration(),MyMRJob.class);
        conf.setJobName("NameofJob");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(CutomeKeyClass.class); //no error to this line
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(MYMap.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(MyReduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(MyReduce.class);


        conf.setInputFormat(CustomInputFormat.class);//ERROR to this line while typing
        conf.setOutputFormat(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

Comment: You'll need to post the error generated by the compiler, and possibly the signature of your CustomInputFormat class (are you including it in the import section for the above code block?)

Comment: @ChrisWhite ..added signature and code ....sign for CustomRecordReader is<code>  class CustomRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text>

Answer (score 2):

Your input format extends InputFormat of the mapreduce package (it extends rather than implements and the signature matches that of the new api), yet your job configuration is using the old API (JobConf rather than Job).

So you'll either need to amend your Custom input format to implement InputFormat (o.a.h.mapred.InputFormat), or amend your job configuration to use the new API (Job)

Answer (score 0):

hey i have faced the same problem then i used the classes from 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce instead of 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred 
its a problem of old and new API and for this dont use JobConf Configuration use Job Configuration only...